# df.to_sql (pyodbc.programmingError)

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df) with 9 columns:

```
Pos  Qty  Price  Auction    tID      Date     From  To   Currency
23   50   0.03    IFA2       DN   2018-07-03   FR   GB      EUR
```

And I try to import index an already existing table in my MSSQL DB with this code:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+username+':'+password+'@'+server+'/'+database+'?driver=SQL+SERVER')
df.to_sql('tablename', engine, if_exists='append')
```

I keep getting this error message:

> (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'BIGINT'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE TABLENAME] (\n\t[index] BIGINT NULL, \n\t[Pos] BIGINT NULL, \n\t[Qty] BIGINT NULL, \n\t[Price] FLOAT(53) NULL, \n\t[Auction] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n\t[tID] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n\t[Date] DATE NULL, \n\t[From] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n\t[To] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n\t[Currency] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n)\n\n']

What is causing this error?

Comment: `CREATE TABLENAME] ` is not valid syntax for creating table

Comment: Spelling mistake from my side. Have edited the error message.

Comment: Can you add enough python code to create a repro?